# How to show multiple libraries uploaded document in a single library in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have more then 50 libraries in site content but I want to show only the 16 libraries document uploaded into a single library. The document should be visible for 30 days only in this library. Can you guys please advise how I can achieve this task in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: SharePoint Server 2013? Then why tag with SharePoint Online? Do you want to use SharePoint Designer for this? If not, why use the tag?  The content search web part can show documents from more than one source, but you can't show a document in another library unless it is actually stored in that library. It's not quite clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @teylyn I have SharePoint server 2013. I want to show on the the uploaded document on the site. I used the content search web part  but it showing all the document. I needed just only for the few library.I want to show 16 library uploaded document in web part out 50 library. This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Then don't tag with SharePoint online, please. That is confusing. You can filter the CSWP to include only specific libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Use the KQL property restrictors to restrict to specific paths only. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

```
terms to search for path:http://SERVER/SITE/LIBRAY1 path:http://SERVER/SITE/LIBRAY2 path:http://SERVER/SITE/LIBRAY3 path:http://SERVER/SITE/LIBRAY4
```

If that is too tedious, you can define a custom result source (aka search scope) for the desire libraries and then use a custom search result page to show these results.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, my understanding is that you want to move documents from libraries to one library after upload the document 30 days.

Use Information Management Policy, define retention stages. 
Under Library Setting -> Information Management Policy Setting -> Enable Retention and Add Retention Stage. you can create retention policy like the following:

[image]

Note: you need to configure send to connection in SharePoint 2013.

1. Activate the Content Organizer for a site collection.

Navigate to a site->Site Settings --> Manage Site Features --> Activate "Content Organizer".

2. Collect the webservice URL to create a trusted location from.

Navigate to the same site->Site Settings --> Content Organizer Settings --> copy the web service URL.

[image]

3. Create a new connection under CA.

Go to Central Administration>General Application Settings>Configure Send To Locations >Paste the copied URL to the field Send to URL and type a display name.

For more detailed information, refer to the following article step by step(which is also work in SharePoint 2013):

http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-configure-send-to-connections-in-sharepoint-2010/

After you have configure send to connection in CA, now you can choose the "transfer to different location".